# Viewing movies/TV programs requires constant mouse movements or keyboard activity to watch

Tags: keyboard, browser, mouse, video-streaming, pause

When viewing a television program using any mainstream browser (Internet Explorer/Firefox/Chrome/SeaMonkey/Safari), it constantly pauses unless I have some kind of activity with either the mouse or the keyboard. The browser with the least amount of problems is SeaMonkey, the one with the most is Internet Explorer.

Any idea of what is causing this or how to prevent it? My finger gets rather tired watching a two-hour movie! :-)

Comment: I don't know the actual cause. But if you just need a solution to the blackout, there are some software which moves mouse cursor few pixels automatically and repeatedly, so that you don't have to.

Comment: Which video-streaming websites or video players are affected by this?

Comment: Post your system specs as this will help.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay – away from my machine for a few days.

Comment: Lamb: do you have any suggestion as to what the best "fake-mouse-move" software might be?

Comment: I usually use "http://www.sidereel.com" for the shows that I view, or Netflix for movies (or for older shows – such as Numb3rs). As I stated before all of the web browsers I have tried, including Firefox/Internet Explorer/Chrome/SeaMonkey and a few others exhibit this problem)

Comment: the general specifications for my machine: a Dell running Windows 7/ultimate -running a dual CPU with Xeon processors fully loaded all the memory a 32-bit will take)

Comment: Next time make sure that you use `@<name>` in comment so that the concerned person gets a notification. I just came across this comment while surfing otherwise, your comment would have gone unnoticed. Anyways I have posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need automated keystroke or mouse movement to prevent the problem, you can achieve this functionality **without** using any **Third Party applications**.  By using a simple **VB Script**, a script which will send predefined keystrokes, after specified amount of time.
[Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457907/how-to-prevent-auto-locking-feature-of-an-xp-machine-using-vbscript).

**Other Solutions:**

- You can use a simple [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script which will send Key-stokes or move mouse cursor  repeatedly after specified amount of time . [Here is one such script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827102/can-someone-help-me-an-autohotkey-script).
- There is a free utility [Move Mouse](http://movemouse.codeplex.com/)  a simple application that simulates user activity. You can either move the mouse pointer, click the left mouse button, send a keystroke, or any combination of the three.
- Another option is [No Sleep](http://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/readynosleepexe-prevents-screensaver-and-pc-locking), it moves your mouse one pixel to the left, and then one pixel to the right every 30 seconds.